# onClick function works on runtime but not on actual click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, runtime

I am trying to redirect the user to another page when a button or menu item is clicked. Unfortunately, the onClick function only works on runtime and not on actual click and I can't figure it out why.

Here is my function

```
  const redirectCreateContact = (index) => {
  history.push({
    state: {category:index},
    pathname:"/apps/contacts/new/"

  });

  return <Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/apps/contacts/new/',
  }}/>;
}

function ContactsHeader(props)
{

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-between p-8 sm:p-24">

            <div className="flex flex-shrink items-center sm:w-224">
                <Hidden lgUp>
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={(ev) => {
                            props.pageLayout.current.toggleLeftSidebar()
                        }}
                        aria-label="open left sidebar"
                    >
                        <Icon>menu</Icon>
                    </IconButton>
                </Hidden>

                <div className="flex items-center">
                    <FuseAnimate animation="transition.expandIn" delay={300}>
                        <Icon className="text-32 mr-12">account_box</Icon>
                    </FuseAnimate>
                    <FuseAnimate animation="transition.slideLeftIn" delay={300}>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className="hidden sm:flex">Contacts</Typography>
                    </FuseAnimate>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center pr-8 sm:px-12">

                <ThemeProvider theme={props.mainTheme}>
                    <FuseAnimate animation="transition.slideLeftIn" delay={300}>
                        <Paper className="flex p-4 items-center w-full max-w-512 px-8 py-4" elevation={1}>

                            <Icon className="mr-8" color="action">search</Icon>

                            <Input
                                placeholder="Search for anything"
                                className="flex flex-1"
                                disableUnderline
                                fullWidth
                                inputProps={{
                               'aria-label': 'Search'
                                }}

                            />
                        </Paper>
                    </FuseAnimate>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </div>

          <div className="flex flex-2 items-center justify-center">
          <FormControl variant="filled" style={{width:"200px"}}>
            <InputLabel >Create New</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
              id="demo-simple-select-filled"
            >
              <Button className='button-redirect' onClick={()=>redirectCreateContact(1)}>New Custom</Button>

              <MenuItem className='button-redirect' onClick={()=>redirectCreateContact(2)}>New Supplier</MenuItem>

            </Select>
          </FormControl>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(ContactsHeader);
```

If I call the function without the call back like this

```
onClick ={redirectCreateContact(2)}
```

it is called at runtime not when the button or menu item is actually clicked. There is nothing wrong with the function that's being called onClick (I've tried console.log-ing something on click with no result).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here `onClick={redirectCreateContact(1)}`

You are executing a function on render.

do `onClick = {() => redirectCreateContact(1)}` and it should be OK.

Comment: I've tried that (as you can see in the MenuItem) it doesn't work for a reason or another.

Comment: Well, this is how it's supposed to be nevertheless. Maybe there is something other than this, but `onClick={redirectCreateContact(1)}` will definitely produce that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

On your **MenuItem** you are calling the **redirectCreatecontact(2)** method differently than on the Button onClick call, is there a reason that you are calling that method by an arrow function? Have you try changing the code to:

```
<MenuItem className='button-redirect' onClick={redirectCreateContact(2)}>New Supplier</MenuItem>
```

I only remove the `()=>`

That is the only difference that I can see

Comment: When you do it like that it will call the function on runtime not when the element is actually clicked.

Comment: Correct, I think it may have something to do the way MenuItem actions the onClick, I'll look into the MaterialUI API to see if I can find anything

Comment: I think you`ve got that wrong. None of the elements, nor the button, nor the menuitem onClick functions work. I've changed the first element calling the onClick function to be a button so I can see if the problems is the element I'm using or the function itself.

Comment: I believe the problem is in your implementation of the MenuItem component, I have not use MaterialUI but I can see in the documentation that it the MenuItem works within a Menu component, and that may be the reason why you dont see the expected result, have you try to change the call to be triggered by a Buton component instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace with as below:

```js
<Button className='button-redirect' onClick={()=>redirectCreateContact(1)}>New Custom</Button>
```

It would be work on both Button as well MenuItem but could you please let me know, is MenuItem kind of component are you importing or else ?

Comment: It doesn't work dude. The only reason I`m using the function without the callback is to show that the function called at runtime i.E onClick = {redirectCreateContact(1)} works while the other doesn't. Trust me I've tried it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, @Octavian could you please let me know about MenuItem?

Comment: It does not work. The problem is the onClick function doing nothing not the element used in the UI.

Comment: Is MenuItem a kind of functional or class component?

Comment: It doesn't matter. But it's a class see https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/ for more details.

Comment: I just tried with code sandbox it's working fine can you please move the redirectCreateContact() inside the functional component. Please have a look below URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/9xigg

Comment: export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const handleClose = (e) => {
    alert(e);
  };
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick=() => handleClose(1)>New custom</button>
        <MenuItem onClick={() => handleClose(2)}>Profile</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203076/discussion-between-govind-soni-and-octavian).